# visible workflow engine with django or python?

Tags: python, django, workflow

Is there visible workflow engine with django or python? in front-end webpage, user could handle workflow without coding via visible workflow interface.
if have these workflow, pls recommend to me its name.
thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by workflow engine? from you description it looks like you are looking for CMS https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/cms/

Comment: No CMS.    according to actual flow work , such request -> approval by p1 -> approval by p2 -> flow work end. user make flow chart based workflow engine, it creates workflow automaticly.

Answer (score 1):

did you mean workflow patterns, like http://workflowpatterns.com/
then in python we have spiff workflow engine: https://github.com/knipknap/SpiffWorkflow

specification is created based on the Business Process Model and Notation (BPMN)

Comment: Thanks a lot ,but SpiffWorkFlow reference is little, hot to use SpiffWorkFlow?